# Edit Action of OpenGraph isn't accessible

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I submitted an action to Facebook OpenGraph and received a message that some thing has to be changed.
When I click on the action at the Facebook Developer site to see what needs to be changed I receive a HTTP 500 ERROR message.
Even when I access another action that is already approved I receive the same error.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

that problem can be because of the web browser!

read about this hear: http://socialmediaseo.net/2010/03/25/facebook-errors-http-500/

what are you trying to do?!

Comment: I just click on the action to see its settings. In chrome I got a error message. In Firefox I just got a blank page. If this is a browser problem, what browser does facebook support?

Comment: Using firebug in Firefox. Bang, http 500